# Assigning session values to user on registration in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need to merge some sort of default(but dynamic) value to user_params while registration. Something like:

`(devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:name, :username]).merge(referred_by_id: session[:referrer_id])`

I know I can make custom sanitization, but no help for **merging some attributes which may come from other than request params**.

Till now I am using after-creation hack, by updating the created record, which is obviously expensive by one redundant db query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look the [Devise source code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) you can see that it calls [`.new_with_session`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Registerable/ClassMethods) on your user class when initializing the user.

> `#new_with_session(params, session) ⇒ Object`
>
> A convenience method that receives both parameters and session to
>   initialize a user. This can be used by OAuth, for example, to send in
>   the user token and be stored on initialization.
>
> By default discards all information sent by the session by calling new
>   with params.

So if you want to assign a value from the session you can simply do it by:

```
# or whatever your "user" class is
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  def self.new_from_session(params, session)
    new(params) do |user|
      user.referred_by_id = session[:referrer_id]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If `referrer_id` is a foreign key you may want to verify that the user actually exists to avoid problems with referential integrity.

Comment: (If it works,) this is obviously a hack anyway, and I don't find sending session variable to Model for manipulating values during creation. My existing hack is better[subjective] (and more manageable), I which I am throwing second update query.

Comment: Also, what I guess, manipulating params and session, should better be done in controller or some controller concerns. I was just searching for something which devise itself would have given as any configurable options/methods

Comment: Its not a hack - its a documented part of the Registerable module and how registrations work in Devise. You could override `#build_resource` in the controller to do something else but Devise is built this way to let you do it from the model so that you don't have override the controller. Also you're not manipulating the params or session - you're just assigning values to an instance in a factory method. If you're gonna be such a stickler then stop using `.new` with a hash...

Comment: Got you. Seems like the only way as of now is overriding the above method only, as suggested by you. Yeah, I am a bit strict. But anyway, for now, your solution solves the problem. And should be the accepted answer thus.

Comment: And don't know who gave that negative vote to this answer, without even any explanation!